# How to receive SE Newsletters for a different account? Also, how to create multiple Stack Exchange accounts (2, actually)?

Tags: support, newsletter

This question does not intend to support sockpuppeting in any way, in fact, the purpose of creating two different accounts on stack exchange is totally different.

I have an account on SE. So whenever I enter some SE site, I see myself as logged in (of course). But, my sister too wants to receive newsletters of different SE sites. So is it "necessary" for her to create a different account in order to receive the newsletters in her email inbox? If yes, then what is the procedure to do it? I mean, whenever I come to some SE site, I don't see any way to get "logged out" and create a totally new account for her.

Comment: You can logout, but an easy workaround is to use like chrome for you, and let her use IE in example, but honnestly you should create her a secondary account in that computer to keep her stuff in it

Comment: The newsletter is sent to the email address which you set in the profile of each site. So you can put her email address in the sites you don't use yourself, and she'll get them to her inbox.

Comment: At best you give your *sister* her own PC. If that is not feasible give here a login on your PC. If that is not feasible have her use firefox while you use Chrome. if that is also not feasible create   an extra [profile on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for her. If that is not feasible, subscribe to all the newsletters and create rules in your email client to forward the newsletters your sister is interested in. Or do what @sha suggests.